# How to extract values from strings

Tags: python, list, binance

Hi I am working on a trading bot and i have a question.How do i extract symbol and price value from this type of string.
I want to store them in different variables like price and symbol.

```
[
    {
        "symbol": "LTCBTC",
        "price": "4.00000200"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "ETHBTC",
        "price": "0.07946600"
    }
]
```

Comment: Read about parsing JSON, and then look into how to use Python's native `json` library.

Comment: just do [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) and access the key of the dictionary

Comment: As far as I understand, you are trying to get the prices of altcoins. Search if there is an API from the site where you are getting the values. That might ease your work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import json

binance_str = '[{"symbol": "LTCBTC", "price": "4.00000200" }, { "symbol": "ETHBTC", "price": "0.07946600"}]'
binance_json = json.loads(binance_str)

for el in binance_json:
    print(el['symbol'])
    print(el['price'])

# Output:
# =======
# LTCBTC
# 4.00000200
# ETHBTC
# 0.07946600
```